# Problema con operciones luego de implementar AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

tengo un problema con mi codigo.

Yo, modifique mi index.html en el cual tenía una tabla con unos servicios web ya que mi pagina es un cotizador web.

Las elimine y agregué ese contenido creando un archivo.JSON con los datos correspondientes, y lo llame mediante jQuery con el método $.getJSON, de esa forme maquete de forma dinámica la tabla que elimine, mencionada antes, ahora el tema es que no me funcionan las operaciones que me hacían los cálculos, no me funcionan después de implementar esto, antes de maquetar todo con ajax funcionaba pero ahora no.

```
$("#confirmar").click(function () {  
    let total = 0;
    let mantenimiento = $('#switchMantenimiento:checked').val()
    total = (parseInt($('input:radio:checked').val()) + ( parseInt($('#nuSecciones').val() * parseInt(precioSecciones))) + parseInt($('#switchMantenimiento:checked').val()));

    totalWeb.innerText = `$ ${total}`;
    });

    let HTMLServices = ""

    const services = (web) => {
    HTMLServices = `<tr id="porfolio">
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input input" type="radio" name="servicios" id="${web.id}" value="${web.precio}">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="${web.id}"> ${web.nombre} </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                        ${web.precio}
                        </td>
                    </tr>`
    return HTMLServices
    }
```

Ese seria el codigo, no se si necesitarian algo mas para ver mejor el funcionamiento de mi codigo.

PD: Antes de ese condigo escrito, todo funcionaba perfecto.

PD2: Edito el código con la solución dada(Aun fallan ciertas cosas).

Comment: ¿Hay alǵún error en la consola?

Comment: Ninguno. Tengo mis variables declaradas con los precio de cada cosa y asi calcular, pero no me funciona, me muestra los valores, de cada cosa que selecciono pero no hace la sumatoria.

EJEMPLO: muestra (3000)(500)(1090)

Lo separe entre parentesis para que se lea mas facil, pero obvio me muestra todos los valores sin parentesis. No se si esta permitido escribir por algun medio para verlo mejor

Comment: Tienes que convertir cada valor a entero con `parseInt()`  o eventualmente `parseFloat()` si hubiera valores con decimales.

Comment: Lo hice pero tampoco me funciono, creo que va por otra cosa

Comment: Edita el código y muestra cómo lo hiciste.

Comment: Editado, en el ejemplo esta con parseFloat() pero lo intente con parseInt() tambien. Te segui en TW

Comment: Tienes que hacer parse de cada valor por separado. Algo así: **`total = ( parseFloat($('input:radio:checked').val()) + ( parseFloat($('#nuSecciones').val()) * parseFloat(precioSecciones) ) + parseFloat($('#switchMantenimiento:checked').val());`**

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ahi me anda, no se me habia ocurrido asi, mis disculpas. Ya me anda pero igual tengo otros problemas, de funcionamiento, espero corregirlos ahi miro el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que debes hacer un parse por cada valor en particular, antes de operar con ellos.

Para hacer un control de los posibles falsos, te recomendaría que recojas cada valor en una variable, así, los posibles falsos valores podrán ser convertidos a `0` con esto `|| 0`, de lo contrario tendrías un `NaN` que rompería la operación.

Por ejemplo:

```
let checkRadio=parseFloat($('input:radio:checked').val()) || 0;
let nuSections=parseFloat($('#nuSecciones').val()) || 0;

/*No sé de dónde viene esta variable, puedes hacer el parse donde la creas*/
let priceSections=parseFloat(precioSecciones) || 0; 
let switchCheck=parseFloat($('#switchMantenimiento:checked').val()) || 0;

/*Aquí todos los valores estarán parseados y no serán NaN en ningún caso*/
total = (checkRadio + (nuSections * priceSections) + switchCheck);
```

Comment: Gracias!! Justamente ahora me arrojaba el famoso NaN en ciertos casos. Me asegurare de hacerlo del modo que comentas. 

Las variables ya las tenia definidas, solo que no las compartí pero no de ese modo que comentas, ya las arreglo!